# CREATE COLUMNFAMILY statement returns SyntaxException: "no viable alternative at input 'with'"

Tags: cassandra

I am learning Cassandra and CQL. I could create the keyspace. While creating the columnfamily, I am getting the error: SyntaxException: line 1:27 no viable alternative at input 'with' (create columnfamily users ([with]...)

I want to know what is wrong in this command:

```
create columnfamily users (
    with 'key_validation_class'='UTF8Type'
    and 'comparator'='UTF8Type'
    and 'default_validation_class'='UTF8Type'
);
```

and how to correct?

While defining the column family, I have not defined any columns with the column family users.

I ran the Cassandra from Docker. I have created 3 instances and could run. I could create few keyspaces and create table command also works fine. In addition I want to try the CREATE columnfamily command also (without defining the columns).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The `CREATE COLUMNFAMILY` syntax has not been supported for a number of years now since it belongs to the very old Cassandra storage format that is associated with the Thrift protocol.

Thrift was deprecated in Cassandra about 9 years ago, replaced by CQL in 2011 ([CASSANDRA-1703](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-1703)). Cassandra 2.2 stopped using Thrift in 2015 ([CASSANDRA-8358](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8358), [CASSANDRA-9319](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9319)) and Cassandra 4.0 completely removed Thrift in 2016 ([CASSANDRA-11115](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11115)).

Instead of "column families" in Thrift, they are now called tables in CQL and [the equivalent command is `CREATE TABLE`](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/ddl.html#create-table-statement).

If you'd like to learn about Cassandra, we have free hands-on tutorials at [datastax.com/dev](https://www.datastax.com/dev). I highly recommend doing the [Cassandra Fundamentals](https://www.datastax.com/learn/cassandra-fundamentals) series so you can quickly learn the basics and you don't have to install anything since everything you need is provided within the tutorials. Cheers!